# How to validate entered embed video (youtube, vimeo) code by user?

Tags: javascript, html, youtube-api, vimeo

I have a control that allows to enter embed video code from Youtube or Vimeo. What is the best way to validate entered data from user to prevent code injection attacks?

PS: I don't want to store template and allow users to enter only URL. Video services could change their api anytime.

Answer (score 1):

While it seems to me that your logic might not be completely sound (because if you're afraid of video services changing their API at any time, you should be likely as afraid, if not more, of those same video services changing their embed format), this would likely be a two step process.

1) validating that what has been entered is trusted HTML (how to do this will depend completely on your implementation ... doing it in javascript, for example, is far different than doing it on the back end in Python, PHP, whatever). If you provide more details as to your setup, you can likely get more targeted response. Probably you'll end up with either a RegEx solution, or a solution based on a parser (I use Beautiful Soup, for example, for Python tag validation, cleanup, and exclusion).

2) validating that you've received workable data for the video source -- this could also be regex, but you may instead want to grab the attribute value and do a quick API call (for example, to the Youtube video list endpoint) to make sure you get a working response.